# How to find the first parent in a tree-like hierarchy using LINQ with EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, tree, ef-core-2.1

I have two entities:

```cs
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } // If the parent is in Child, the that Id, otherwise a random Guid.
    public string ParentId { get; set; }  // Id of the parent of this parent.
    public string ChildId { get; set; }   // Id of the child from the Child class.
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

The Db context is set up like:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
       builder.Entity<Child>();
       builder.Entity<Parent>().HasKey(k => new {k.Id, k.ChildId});
       builder.Entity<Parent>()
              .HasOne(h => h.Child)
              .WithMany(w => w.Parents)
              .IsRequired()
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
   }
}
```

Actual data is such that, not every parent is in the `Child` table but every child is in the `Child` table. I want to query children (from the `Child` table) who happened to be the top most parent in a parent-child hierarchy. For example:

```
        /*
         * Tree:
         *     p1(P)--------p2 (P)------r2 (P&C)
         *      |-----------|           |
         *      |                       c3 (P&C)
         *      |                       |
         *      |                      gc1 (C)
         *     r1 (P&C)---|
         *      |         |
         *     c1 (C)     c2 (C)
         */
```

This tree should yield `r1` and `r2` for solution as they are at the top of a tree and also in the child table. In other words, they do not have a parent who is also a child.

My attempt so far is:

```cs
using(var ctx = new MyContext(options))
{
    var q = ctx.Set<Child>();
    var mainQ = q.GroupJoin(q.Where(w => w.Parents.Any()),
                            o => o.Id,
                            i => i.Parents.First().ParentId /* For now I'm just trying to handle a single parent.*/,
                           (o, i) => new { o, i })
                 .Where(w => !w.i.Any())
                 .Select(s => s.o)
                 .Union(q.Where(w => !w.Parents.Any()));
}
```

However, this query gives me the error:

> ArgumentException: The input sequence must have items of type Child but it has items of type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AnonymousObject

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: why is it required to have both a parent and child class, separately? wouldn't a `Node` class be enough? having  `public Node Parent` and `public Node Child`?

Comment: @Stucky It cannot be done due to reasons outside the scope of this question. I have a need to store them separately.

Comment: so the classes can not be changed in any way?

Comment: @Stucky No, sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to figure it out :)

```
var childIds = ctx.Set<Child>().Select(s => s.Id);

var query = ctx.Set<Child>()
    .GroupJoin(ctx.Set<Parent>(), o => o.Id, i => i.Id, (o, i) => new {o, i})
    .Where(w => w.i.Any())
    .Select(s => s.o)
    .Include(i => i.Parents)
    .Where(w => !w.Parents.Select(s => s.Id).Intersect(childIds).Any());
```

Idea is to find all children who are parents (`GroupJoin` followed by `Where` clause) and then check if the parents of those children are in children table.

If someone has a better/more performant solution, please post an answer.